# How to subscribe to Firestore data using Stream

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I'm adopting a layered architecture and using Riverpod as state management.

I would like to subscribe to Firestore data, but I have no idea how to implement it.

I was able to define the data source as follows.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'news_data_source.g.dart';


Stream<News?> newsDataSource(NewsDataSourceRef ref) async* {
  yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('News')
      .doc('news')
      .snapshots()
      .map(
        (snap) =>
            snap.data() == null ? null : News.fromFirestore(snap.data()!),
      );
}
```

Next, I want to create a repository that calls the data source, but an error occurs.

```
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'news_repository_provider.g.dart';

NewsRepository newsRepository(NewsRepositoryRef ref) {
  NewsRepository(
    newsDataSourceRef: ref.watch(newsDataSourceProvider),  // <- ERROR
  );
}

class NewsRepository {
  NewsRepository({
    required Stream<News?> newsDataSourceRef,
  }) : _newsDataSourceRef = newsDataSourceRef;

  final Stream<News?> _newsDataSourceRef;

  Stream<News?> listenNews() {
    return  _newsDataSourceRef;
  }
}
```

The following error text indicating that the type is incorrect will be output.

> The argument type 'AutoDisposeStreamProvider<News?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<Stream<News?>>'.

How can I get `Stream<News>?`